# Java, search for elements of an string array and write them into another array

Tags: java, arrays, string

I am looking for a solution how I can get an array of contains from another one.

For example:
I have an array:
**Array= [S1!!T1, S1!!T2, S1!!T3, S2!!T1, S2!!T2, S3!!T1, S3!!T2, S3!!T3]**

I am looking for elements in "Array" that contain "S2" and write them to another one. so i should get:

**Result = [S2!!T1, S2!!T2]**

I already tried the `Arrays.asList(I).contains(i)` but this is not what i am lookig for i think.

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far

Comment: Hint: understand the difference between what the *array* (or list) contains, and between what each of the *strings* contains.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to copy elements of one array to another, first thing you need to do is loop through the elements of one array and if you find a match then store it into another array.

Let's say you have the following array:

```
String[] arr = new String[]{"S1!!T1", "S1!!T2", "S1!!T3", "S2!!T1", "S2!!T2", "S3!!T1", "S3!!T2", "S3!!T3"};
```

We don't know how many of those elements in the array are going to match until we loop through them so we have two choice:

1. Create another array with the same size as arr (cause some null values in array if not all entries of arr re matched)
2. Use ArrayList and then later convert ArrayList to array if needed

See below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] arr = new String[]{"S1!!T1", "S1!!T2", "S1!!T3", "S2!!T1", "S2!!T2", "S3!!T1", "S3!!T2", "S3!!T3"};
        List<String> s2List = new ArrayList<String>(); 

        //loop through arr and for each element check if it contains S2
        for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            //if it contains S2 then it returns true and we add it to list
            if(arr[i].contains("S2")) {
                //add to list the element
                s2List.add(arr[i]); 
            }
        }

        //print the list for testing
        System.out.println(s2List); 

        //if you wish to store the elements to array then

        //now we know how many matched, so we can create array with the 
        //size of elements in s2List 
        String[] sArr = new String[s2List.size()]; 

        //Here loop through the list and assign values to array
        for(int i = 0;  i < s2List.size() ; i++) {
            sArr[i] = s2List.get(i); 
        }

        //print the array
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sArr));
    }
```

You can also use other methods that convert a List to array directly but, above should give you an idea of how to resolve the question you asked.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Java 8 streams

```
String[] filtered = Stream.of(strings).filter(s -> s.contains("S2")).toArray(String[]::new);
```